# UIWebView Causing UI Lockup. No Crash or Logs

Tags: ios, uiwebview

The set up is quite simple.

Root Controller is a tab bar controller.  One of my tabs has a navigation controller with a tableview.  Button in nav bar is supposed to push UIViewController with a simple UIWebView onto the stack.  When that button is pushed, the UI locks up.

I took out all the code that would load a webpage but that didn't help.

There is nothing in the console.  No dramatic increases in memory or CPU usage.  Nothing is thrown and according to the debuggers the app is running fine.

I reduced it to the point where I have a blank view controller for the webview minus the property for IB and a storyboard segue.

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it was just a corrupted Storyboard file.  I just cleared it out and started from scratch.  Seems to work fine now.